# JavaScript condition not taking into account the variable defined within a function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to append text within an HTML file, but only when `is_sum_1 == true`. I want the user to select something from a dropdown box before the conditional text gets appended, but the `if` statement seems to only become satisfied when `var is_sum_1 = true;` is outside of the function.

**JavaScript function:**

```
function dropDownListener(input_id, output_id) {
   var dropDown = document.getElementById(input_id);
   var is_sum_1 = true;

   dropDown.onchange = function() {
      document.getElementById(output_id).innerHTML = dropDown.value;
   }

dropDownListener('sum_1', 'print_sum_1');
```

**Printing output and conditional text in HTML:**

```
<div id="summary">
   <span id="print_sum_1"></span>

   <script>
      if (is_sum_1) {
         $('#summary').append("I'm trying to append text if condition met")
      }
   </script>
</div>
```

Comment: `is_sum_1` is outside the scope of your `<script>`, which is defined at the global level, where your `is_sum_1` is defined only within the scope of the function `dropDownListener`. Also, FYI, inside `dropDown.onchange`, you can use `this.value` instead of `dropDown.value`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: there is no dropdown in HTML, you mean a Select or a detail element?